# How to remap mouse keys? (special case)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xbindkeys

I remapped 2 mouse buttons, #4 and #7. Now they are used as 'Home' and 'End' keys, very useful in firefox.
Unfortunately **all the extra keys on my mouse are identical to the numeric keys on the keyboard**, mind you I'm not referring to the numeric keypad, so now if I press the 4 key on the keyboard it's like pressing the 4 key on the mouse or 'Home' on the keyboard.

xev confirms all of the above
This is when I press the number 4 mouse button:

```
KeyPress event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001, 
root 0x78a, subw 0x0, time 2268616, (164,-23), root:(1035,458), 
state 0x10, keycode 13 (keysym 0x34, 4), same_screen YES, 
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (34) "4" 
XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (34) "4" 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

This is when I press the number 4 keyboard button:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
root 0x78a, subw 0x0, time 3661443, (169,-15), root:(1040,466),
state 0x10, keycode 13 (keysym 0x34, 4), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (34) "4"
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

As you can see **pressing the 4 key of the mouse or the 4 key of the keyboard is the same thing**.

I would like to understand if **it is possible to remap the mouse keys upstream**, in such a way that even xev results in different codes from the current ones.